# first/ last vs min/max. ORACLE. SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the query and the result of the query:

```
SELECT empno,
       deptno,
       sal,
       MIN(sal) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sal) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno) "Lowest",
       MAX(sal) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY sal) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno) "Highest"
FROM   emp
ORDER BY deptno, sal;

     EMPNO     DEPTNO        SAL     Lowest    Highest
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7934         10       1300       1300       5000
      7782         10       2450       1300       5000
      7839         10       5000       1300       5000
      7369         20        800        800       3000
      7876         20       1100        800       3000
      7566         20       2975        800       3000
      7788         20       3000        800       3000
      7902         20       3000        800       3000
      7900         30        950        950       2850
      7654         30       1250        950       2850
      7521         30       1250        950       2850
      7844         30       1500        950       2850
      7499         30       1600        950       2850
      7698         30       2850        950       2850

SQL>
```

Would it return the same result **without** KEEP statement? WHy or why not?

P.S. I would have checked it myself but do not have a database access on the current machine.

Comment: You can test it yourself in [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com). It's not that I don't want to answer but it seems you don't know about this tool.

Comment: doesnt seem to work for me though :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your tags, I assume you are in Oracle:

- [Example with the `KEEP` statement.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe83e/1)

  ```
  EMPNO | DEPTNO  | SAL   | LOWEST | HIGHEST
  7934  | 10      | 1300  | 1300   | 5000
  7782  | 10      | 2450  | 1300   | 5000
  7839  | 10      | 5000  | 1300   | 5000
  7369  | 20      |  800  |  800   | 3000
  7876  | 20      | 1100  |  800   | 3000
  7566  | 20      | 2975  |  800   | 3000
  7788  | 20      | 3000  |  800   | 3000
  7902  | 20      | 3000  |  800   | 3000
  7900  | 30      |  950  |  950   | 2850
  7654  | 30      | 1250  |  950   | 2850
  7521  | 30      | 1250  |  950   | 2850
  7844  | 30      | 1500  |  950   | 2850
  7499  | 30      | 1600  |  950   | 2850
  7698  | 30      | 2850  |  950   | 2850
  ```
- [Example without the `KEEP` statement.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe83e/4)

  ```
  EMPNO | DEPTNO  | SAL   | LOWEST | HIGHEST
  7934  | 10      | 1300  | 1300   | 5000
  7782  | 10      | 2450  | 1300   | 5000
  7839  | 10      | 5000  | 1300   | 5000
  7369  | 20      |  800  |  800   | 3000
  7876  | 20      | 1100  |  800   | 3000
  7566  | 20      | 2975  |  800   | 3000
  7788  | 20      | 3000  |  800   | 3000
  7902  | 20      | 3000  |  800   | 3000
  7900  | 30      |  950  |  950   | 2850
  7654  | 30      | 1250  |  950   | 2850
  7521  | 30      | 1250  |  950   | 2850
  7844  | 30      | 1500  |  950   | 2850
  7499  | 30      | 1600  |  950   | 2850
  7698  | 30      | 2850  |  950   | 2850
  ```

As you can see (and test) both output the same results.

`MIN(sal) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sal)` means "sort the rows by sal, and pick only those rows which have the smallest value of sal. If you have more rows with the same sal, the min function at the start tells Oracle to pick the one with the minimum value of sal."

In this case, as the order in the `DENSE_RANK FIRST` and the `MIN()` are with the same column, both are doing the same, so I would suggest not using `KEEP` here for performance matters.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. This was my guess, but now i know for sure xx

Answer (score 1):

Oracle [documents its behavior](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions065.htm).

> The KEEP keyword is for semantic clarity. It qualifies
>   aggregate_function, indicating that only the FIRST or LAST values of
>   aggregate_function will be returned.